# Fetch records from intermediate table or fetch all if they don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have following database schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableType]
    (
    [id]       INT NOT NULL, 
    [name]     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC), 
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ColumnType]
    (
    [id]       INT NOT NULL, 
    [name]     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ColumnType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC), 
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableTypeAllowedObjectType]
    (
    [id]                    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    [id_table_type]         INT NOT NULL,
    [id_column_type]        INT NOT NULL,
    [default_value]         BIT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableTypeAllowedObjectType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TableTypeAllowedColumnType_ColumnType] FOREIGN KEY ([id_column_type]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ColumnType]([id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TableTypeAllowedColumnType_TableType] FOREIGN KEY ([id_table_type]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TableType]([id]),
)
```

Data sample:

```sql
DELETE FROM dbo.TableTypeAllowedObjectType;
DELETE FROM dbo.TableType;
DELETE FROM dbo.ColumnType;

INSERT INTO dbo.TableType (id, name) values (1, 'TableType1');
INSERT INTO dbo.TableType (id, name) values (2, 'TableType2');

INSERT INTO dbo.ColumnType (id, name) values (1, 'ColumnType1');
INSERT INTO dbo.ColumnType (id, name) values (2, 'ColumnType2');
INSERT INTO dbo.ColumnType (id, name) values (3, 'ColumnType3');

INSERT INTO dbo.TableTypeAllowedObjectType (id_table_type, id_column_type, default_value) values(1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO dbo.TableTypeAllowedObjectType (id_table_type, id_column_type, default_value) values(1, 2, 0);
```

I need to fetch all `ColumnType` records for `id_table_type` if there are any in `[dbo].[TableTypeAllowedObjectType]`. If there aren't any records for particular `id_table_type` then query should return all `ColumnType` records.

Supposed query for TableType1 should look like this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ColumnType ... WHERE id_table_type = 1
```

and return ColumnType records:

```
1   ColumnType1
2   ColumnType2
```

Supposed query for TableType2 should return all records:

```
1   ColumnType1
2   ColumnType2
3   ColumnType3
```

in this particular sample I need to get all ColumnType records for TableType2 and ColumnTypes 1 and 2 for TableType1.

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7b6ae/1)

Any ideas how to achieve this in more or less efficient way?

Thanks.

Comment: `id_folder_type` doesn't exist in your table; where is it coming from?

Comment: Can you post DML for your sample DDL please, as well as the expected results **and** your attempt(s) please?

Comment: I fixed it, it is id_table_type instead of id_folder_type.

Comment: Can you show your attempt(s) and the expected results for your sample data please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I was able to get working in SSMS:

```
-- Sample tables.
DECLARE @TableType TABLE ( [id] INT NOT NULL, [name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );
DECLARE @ColumnType TABLE ( [id] INT NOT NULL, [name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );
DECLARE @TableTypeAllowedObjectType TABLE (
    [id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, [id_table_type] INT NOT NULL, [id_column_type] INT NOT NULL, [default_value] BIT NOT NULL
);

-- Sample data.
INSERT INTO @TableType (id, [name]) VALUES (1, 'TableType1'), (2, 'TableType2');
INSERT INTO @ColumnType (id, [name]) VALUES (1, 'ColumnType1'), (2, 'ColumnType2'), (3, 'ColumnType3');
INSERT INTO @TableTypeAllowedObjectType (id_table_type, id_column_type, default_value) VALUES (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0);

-- Variable for table type id.
DECLARE @TableTypeID INT = 1;

-- Query data based on table type id.
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @TableTypeAllowedObjectType WHERE id_table_type = @TableTypeID )
    SELECT * FROM @ColumnType AS ColumnType
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM @TableTypeAllowedObjectType AS AllowedType
        WHERE 
            ColumnType.id = AllowedType.id_column_type
            AND AllowedType.id_table_type = @TableTypeID
    )
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM @ColumnType AS ColumnType
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM @TableTypeAllowedObjectType AS AllowedType
        WHERE 
            ColumnType.id = AllowedType.id_column_type
            AND AllowedType.id_table_type = @TableTypeID
    )
```

@TableTypeID = 1 returns:

```
+----+-------------+
| id |    name     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | ColumnType1 |
|  2 | ColumnType2 |
+----+-------------+
```

@TableTypeID = 2 returns:

```
+----+-------------+
| id |    name     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | ColumnType1 |
|  2 | ColumnType2 |
|  3 | ColumnType3 |
+----+-------------+
```

I believe this is what you're looking for?

**UPDATE:** Adding functionality to a TVF.

You can add this functionality to a Table Valued Function that should be able to be called from your View. Here's an example based on what information is available here:

```
-- Create TVF.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTableTypeColumns (
    @TableTypeID INT
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE (
    id INT, [name] VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN


    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM dbo.TableTypeAllowedObjectType WHERE id_table_type = @TableTypeID ) BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @Results ( id, [name] )
        SELECT * FROM dbo.ColumnType
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM dbo.TableTypeAllowedObjectType AS AllowedType
            WHERE 
                ColumnType.id = AllowedType.id_column_type
                AND AllowedType.id_table_type = @TableTypeID
        )

    END ELSE BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @Results ( id, [name] )
        SELECT * FROM dbo.ColumnType
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM dbo.TableTypeAllowedObjectType AS AllowedType
            WHERE 
                ColumnType.id = AllowedType.id_column_type
                AND AllowedType.id_table_type = @TableTypeID
        )

    END

    RETURN

END
GO
```

Once you have created the TVF you can call it like so:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetTableTypeColumns( 1 );
```

**Returns**

```
+----+-------------+
| id |    name     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | ColumnType1 |
|  2 | ColumnType2 |
+----+-------------+
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetTableTypeColumns( 2 );
```

**Returns**

```
+----+-------------+
| id |    name     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | ColumnType1 |
|  2 | ColumnType2 |
|  3 | ColumnType3 |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is it possible to rewrite this query in order to use it inside view?

Comment: You can wrap this in a Table Valued Function and then reference the TVF in your view.